# Equivalent of php's mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: delphi, escaping, dynamic-sql

I have a need for some dynamic SQL to INSERT a large number of values into a database.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a,b,c,d) VALUES (1,2,3,'string with possible quotes'),....
```

Because I want to insert about a 1,000 rows per batch, parameters are not really an option.
In php I'd use the `mysql_` lib and `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent errors and SQL-injections.

How do I escape the string values in Delphi?

Comment: Although protection from SQL injection is the more common reason for touting parameterized queries, another benefit of them is that they save the DB engine from having to re-parse a query each time it's sent. Batching serves the same purpose. Either way, the DB engine can parse the `INSERT ... VALUES` part just once, and the re-run it with different values. So maybe you don't really need to use the batching extension of your database; parameters might give you the same thing without having to escape all your parameters or generate SQL dynamically.

Comment: @RobKennedy, Good point, I timed the query both ways. The main factor here was network traffic overhead, I guess that's why a batch worked out faster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sometime ago I wrote a delphi equivalent function, following the MySql Documentation about the [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) function.

> The string in from is encoded to an escaped SQL string, taking into
>   account the current character set of the connection. The result is
>   placed in to and a terminating null byte is appended. Characters
>   encoded are “\”, “'”, “"”, NUL (ASCII 0), “\n”, “\r”, and Control+Z.
>   Strictly speaking, MySQL requires only that backslash and the quote
>   character used to quote the string in the query be escaped.
>   mysql_real_escape_string() quotes the other characters to make them
>   easier to read in log files

obviously the part `..taking into  account the current character set of the connection` is ignored here.

```
function StringReplaceExt(const S : string; OldPattern, NewPattern:  array of string; Flags: TReplaceFlags):string;
var
 i : integer;
begin
   Assert(Length(OldPattern)=(Length(NewPattern)));
   Result:=S;
   for  i:= Low(OldPattern) to High(OldPattern) do
    Result:=StringReplace(Result,OldPattern[i], NewPattern[i], Flags);
end;

function mysql_real_escape_string(const unescaped_string : string ) : string;
begin
  Result:=StringReplaceExt(unescaped_string,
    ['\', #39, #34, #0, #10, #13, #26], ['\\','\'#39,'\'#34,'\0','\n','\r','\Z'] ,
    [rfReplaceAll]
  );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a million, the current character set is UTF-8. But I'm using ansi-string to input the data, because it comes from an old access database. I just want to be on the safe side and do the right thing, so this code will serve just fine.